# How to format eCharts Treemap elements in specific green or red color depending on item values?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am showing data in a treemap using the eCharts library. Now I want to display the treemap node colors according to the node value, in this example value[1] (remark: the other value[0] determines the node/segment size in my example).

I want to **set specific thresholds**, i.e. values >=5 should be dark green while >=0 but <5 should be regular green, etc. See my code (which doesn't lead to the intended result) and also JSFiddle link below.

I have tried to set color ranges, e.g. a red-to-green color range using `color: ['red', 'white', 'green']` which works fine with 'normal' values, but it works poorly when there are outliers/extremes. Example: 4 nodes, values [-10, -3, 4, 10000]. The first three nodes will be displayed red although the node (4) should actually be displayed in green color, caused by the outlier 1000 which distorts the value range.

```
option = {
  series: [{
    type: 'treemap',
    visualDimension: 1,
    colorMappingBy: 'value',
    levels: [{
      itemStyle: {
        color: function(params) {
          a = params.value[1];
          if (a >= 5) {
            return 'darkgreen';
          } else if (a >= 0 && a < 5) {
            return 'green';
          } else if (a <= -5) {
            return 'darkred';
          } else {
            return 'red';
          }
        },
        normal: {
          borderWidth: 5,
          borderColor: '#eee',
          gapWidth: 5
        }
      }
    }, {
      itemStyle: {
        normal: {
          borderWidth: 2,
          borderColor: '#fff',
          gapWidth: 2
        }
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      name: 'node1',
      value: [5, -10],
    }, {
      name: 'node2',
      value: [10, -4]
    }, {
      name: 'node3',
      value: [15, 3]
    }, {
      name: 'node4',
      value: [8, 1000]
    }]
  }]
};
myChart.setOption(option);
```

I am grateful for any tipps and suggestions to solve this. Thanks!

JSFiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/frankmarks/szm1f20j/34/

Comment: How did you format the tree data?  Echarts doesn't document the format of [disk.tree.json](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-disk) anywhere that I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the solution in the eCharts gallery, which uses a function convertData() to align the color values so it works even with outliers and nicely formats positive nodes with green and negative with red color.

Link here: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=treemap-visual